# Can Javascript objects be accessed like arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Assuming an object is initialized as following:

```
var myObj = {
   "key1":"val1",
   "key2":"val2",
   "key3":"val3",
   ...
};
```

Can I retrieve key values like this?

```
var retrKey1 = myObj[0];
var retrKey2 = myObj[1];
var retrKey3 = myObj[2];
...
```

The issue I am trying to solve is that I need to pick random key values from this object. Generating a random number is not an issue, but:

1. How can I retrieve the number of keys in the object/map?
2. Can I retrieve the key values using a integer index like in arrays?

If not, what are my options?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Object.keys method returns an array of object properties. You can index the array with numbers then.

```
var myObj = {
 "key1":"val1",
 "key2":"val2",
 "key3":"val3",
 ...
};
var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: The order isn't guaranteed. You might have different results in different engines/browsers/executions.

Comment: Since the OP is looking for random key values, ordering and consistency between implementations is moot. Given a random `x` in `0..maxKey`, their random property will be `myObj[keys[x]]`. I think that's exactly what they're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

No, because there's no ordering among property keys. If you want ordered keys, you need to work with an array.

You could define a structure like this :

```
var myObj = [
    {key:"key1", val:"val1"},
    ...
];
```

Comment: He can use `myobj['property']` too

Comment: @steo I understand from the question that OP wants to use "an integer index", not the property name.

Comment: yeah I was not blaming you